# How to solve a white screen problem in the GD library?

Tags: php, gd

I have a problem in the GD PHP library. When I send an image to a localhost VM the image is normally generated on the screen, but when I try to do it on a VPS I do not generate the image and the screen is white. I have already checked if the lib GD is the same on both machines and everything seems to be okay.

The following is the code that I'm generating the image on the screen:

```php
    $image = imagecreatefrompng((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" . "/wp-content/uploads/cart1.png");

    $imageCart = imagecreatefrompng($perfil);

    $titleColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $gray = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 100, 100);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

    imagecopymerge($image, $imageCart, 60, 177, 0, 0, imagesx($imageCart), imagesy($imageCart), 100);

    imagestring($image, 5, 170, 175, "NOME  " . strtoupper($nomeCompleto), $titleColor);
    imagestring($image, 5, 170, 205, "CPF  " . $cpf, $titleColor);
    imagestring($image, 5, 170, 235, "MATRICULA  " . $matricula, $titleColor);
    imagestring($image, 5, 170, 263, "DT NASCIMENTO " . $dtnacimento, $titleColor);

    header("Content-type: image/png");

    imagepng($image);
    imagepng($imageCart);

    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($imageCart);
```

Comment: The function `imagepng()` will echo the image to stdout, but you have used it twice here. You can't send two images to a single image endpoint.

Comment: For the function `imagecreatefrompng`, why are you reading the image over HTTP? Can you not read it from the local file system instead? I wonder if the file operations don't support HTTP on this host.

Comment: Hi, Halfer ...
as I'm doing a merge of two images one on top of the other I thought I would have to launch both in imagepng () ...

The question of http or https is to get the image link wherever it is, it would be to reuse the code.

Comment: OK, there's two issues here. So, no - you need to use `imagepng`. What this does is effectively `echo $image_data`, assuming `$image_data` contained the binary data of your image. If you have merged your images then you should only need to echo one of them - which one is it?

Comment: The first line should just read the image from the disk, and not over HTTP, unless perhaps the image is not served from your local disk. Fix the other issue first though.

Comment: Okay, I'll correct the considerations done and test, I just don't understand why localhost works and in a VPS it doesn't.

Comment: You can add some debugging statements in your VPS to find that out. There are plenty of possible environmental differences (GD is not installed, file operations are not allowed to use HTTPS based on PHP security settings). I wonder if the double image results in what we call "undefined behaviour" with your particular browser - i.e. sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't.

Comment: I made the considerations and the screen is still blank when I send it.

I already checked the lib GD on the two servers, localhost and VPS and they are identical.

Comment: In that case, comment out the `imagepng()` in the non-working copy and the `header()`, and add in text output to debug. You need to check every return value from every function call, for the reasons I outlined above. Check your PHP logs on the box too.

Comment: Library problem I rule out, because the basic function below works.

header("Content-Type: image/png");

$image = imagecreate(256, 256);

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);

imagestring($image, 5, 60, 120, "PHP7", $red);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

Comment: I'll try to redo debugging line by line and tell you the result.

Comment: I managed to locate only that I don't know how to solve it ..
On the line where I have $ image = imagecreatefrompng ("https: //site/local/cart1.png"); is not accepting, now if I put the image in the root where the .php file is and make $ image = imagecreatefrompng ("cart1.png"); it works.
Now how should I do? because the $ imageCart image is a link to a system repository, there is no way to put it elsewhere ...

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be that ("file operations are not allowed to use HTTPS"). Is the file in a predictable/known position within the filing system? You can do something like `imagecreatefrompng ("../../../wp-content/uploads/cart1.png")` (edit to suit). The `..` device traverses up the directory structure, and you can repeat this as many times as you need. This approach reads from the file system rather than from the web server, and reading from the file system is far more efficient.

Comment: very good, I will test it now.

Comment: Thank you very much Halfer, I didn't know this HTTPS issue, as an internal link it works, that's why it always worked on localhost.
Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem was interesting, since the local and remote server environments were reported in the comments as being the same. The usual problem is that the `gd` extension is installed in one, and missing in the other, but that was not the case here. They were even reported as being of the same internal version number.

So the first problem is here:

```
imagepng($image);
imagepng($imageCart);
```

The `imagepng()` function takes the binary data of an image and sends it to `/dev/stdout`, where it will be captured by the web server, and transmitted to the requesting client. Having two of these could make for an odd result, since the browser will see two concatenated PNG images. As mentioned in the comments, this might work for some browsers, and might not for others - in other words we can't rely on it working. It is best to send only valid output, even if we can get it to work in some cases (where it worked, the browser probably used the first one and discarded the second). So the first thing to do was to only send one image.

The next problem was in this line, found by debugging:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") .
    "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" .
    "/wp-content/uploads/cart1.png");
```

Essentially, this loads a source PNG image via HTTP/HTTPS. This takes advantage of a feature in PHP that allows URLs to be used in place of file paths. From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

I would hazard a guess then that your `allow_url_fopen` is true on your local machine, and false or not set on your VPS. This could have been made to work by changing it remotely, but the fix that was made was probably better - and that is to load it from the file system directly.

If you use the fopen wrapper, then what you are actually doing is to make a request of the web server, which fetches the image from disk, and then returns it via curl. So by fetching the image directly using its filename, you are "cutting out the middleman" and getting it more efficiently.

It is normal to use the directory traversal operator in these cases, to create a pathname that is relative to the script's directory. A perfectly good solution, which was used, is:

```
imagecreatefrompng("../../../wp-content/uploads/cart1.png")
```

You can also use a magic variable (assuming the script is three levels down from the project root):

```
$projectDir = realpath(__DIR__ . "/../../..");
imagecreatefrompng($projectDir . "/wp-content/uploads/cart1.png")
```

You will probably find that WordPress sets some of its own project directory constants, so they could have been used in this case too.